# Имя файла, в котором выполнился метод, C++

Tags: c++, логирование

**Обращаюсь к великим мыслителям.**

Дела такие: Работаю над системой логирования. Необхiдно получить имя файла, в котором выполнился метод, что вывел в файл строку.
К примеру:

```
// file-a.cpp
Logger::log("Message from %filename%");
```

Так вот, мне нужно вместо %filename% вывести file-a.cpp, при условии, что файл **не** главный исполняемый.

Comment: [`std::source_location::current().file_name()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location)

Answer (score 1):

Вы о макросе `__FILE__`? См. [тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace#:%7E:text=__FILE__,directive%0A(macro%20constant)).

```
// file-a.cpp
Logger::log("Message from " __FILE__);
```